# Blue prism - Scrolling a web page

Tags: blueprism

Is there any way that we can scroll down in a webpage till an element where we want any verification or want to enter values ?

Another question is that I used global send keys to scroll a page. It works in object studio if I provide an interval of 0 (as inputs set tends to Yes), but from process studio I get an error as follows

"Internal : Failed To perform Step 1 In Navigate Stage 'Trying scroll' on page 'Select hotel' - Special characters (~{}+^%) are not supported in SendKeys if an interval value is provided. Separate calls can be used to send control characters."

how to overcome such situation ?

Comment: From what I understand, Object studio is for all the operations that robat have to do to make something ex. scroll down a webpage and enter some values. Process studio is for creating a logic out from all the objects that you created in Object studio.

Comment: Thats fine, but if scrolling is working in Object studio it shouldn't throw weird error from process studio thats what I think

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the interval = 0. If this doesn't work, can you please share a screenshot of your action inside the object and the Navigation stage that you are using to send keys?